# Is this safe extractor fan wires exposed bathroom

Tags: electrical, plumbing

We have had an extractor fan put in our bathroom by our landlord, but there are exposed wires behind the fan, which is directly next to the shower. It's connected to the light switch with no isolation on or off with the light. Is this safe, the wire is red.[image] picture is the top of the fan thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've cleaned up your question a bit, but it's still hard to tell what's going on. Would you add a picture of the wiring? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Please explain: is the fan mounted in the ceiling or the wall?  By "exposed wires"do you mean wires with full insulation but visible thru the fan grating?  That's not a problem, as opposed to wiring with junctions that aren't inside a box.

Comment: Thank you, the fan is well based

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 2):

The extractor fan should have a junction box for the splice. There should be a cable like Romex or conduit encasing individual wires. As this is a rental, in the US electrical work in most jurisdictions is required to be done by a licensed electrician or possibly a handyman if it was a replacement, 
From your description it would not meet code. 
A photo of the wiring would get a better answer.